# Why does this node CL generate multiple prompts?

Tags: node.js, stdin

I'm noticing a strange behavior in node when working on the command line directly with stdin/stdout.  This program should prompt you to enter some text, appends the text to a file fp.txt, then prompt you to do it again ad infinitum

```
var fs = require('fs'), stdin = process.stdin, stdout = process.stdout;

function prompt() {
  stdout.write('Enter text: ');
  stdin.resume();
  stdin.setEncoding('utf8');
  stdin.on('data', enter);
}

function enter(data) {
  stdin.pause(); // this should terminate stdin
  fs.open('fp.txt', 'a', 0666, function (error, fp) {   
    fs.write(fp, data, null, 'utf-8', function() {
        fs.close(fp, function(error) {
            prompt();
        });
      });
  });
}

prompt();
```

After the second entry, the prompt will fire twice, then four times.  (more than that I get a warning)

```
Enter text: foo
Enter text: bar
Enter text: Enter text: baz
Enter text: Enter text: Enter text: Enter text: qux
```

fp.txt shows 1 foo, 2 bar, 4 baz and 8 qux.  Is there a way to keep a single text-entry loop going using just process.stdin and process.stdout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you call `prompt()` you're adding a new event listener to `stdin`. Then, every time you're entering something new on the `stdin` stream, it's calling all the event listeners you've previously added.

You should call it once at the very start of your script instead (you might as well put `setEncoding` there too):

```
var fs = require('fs'), stdin = process.stdin, stdout = process.stdout;

stdin.setEncoding('utf8');
stdin.on('data', enter);

function prompt() {
  stdout.write('Enter text: ');
  stdin.resume();
}
```